# How does a DispatchQueue work? (specifically multithreading)

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I don't understand the workings of a `DispatchQueue` and wanted to learn more about how they implement the foundational queueing theory requirements. I tried to inspect a queue using:

```
dump(DispatchQueue.global())
```

And this gave this output:

```
- <OS_dispatch_queue_global: com.apple.root.default-qos[0x10c041f00] = { xref = -2147483648, ref = -2147483648, sref = 1, target = [0x0], width = 0xfff, state = 0x0060000000000000, in-barrier}> #0
  - super: OS_dispatch_queue
    - super: OS_dispatch_object
      - super: OS_object
        - super: NSObject
```

I got that the label is `com.apple.root.default-qos`, and this is specified in the Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2300059-init) and the class is the packaged `OS_dispatch_queue_global`. I understand `qos` is queryable on the queue itself and that makes sense as well. Width I think just means the allocated memory size.

What I don't understand are the relevances of `xref`, `ref` and `sref`, I think they are internal ids for the queues but I am not sure. I think they are related to fundamental queueing concepts (multithreading came to mind) but would be great to hone into this in more detail.

Is the `autoreleaseFrequency` hidden from this debug description? Also, what does `in-barrier = 0` mean? I tried creating a custom queue and this was replaced by `in-flight = 0`.. so confused about that as well.

Any ideas on how these undocumented variables relate to queueing theory? I think these are undocumented internals of the API, so any educated and justified explanations would be fine!

Thanks.

Comment: "I tried to inspect a thread" No. It's a queue.

Comment: Sorry I have changed that now.

Comment: Yes but you do it throughout. The way you keep saying "thread" when you mean "queue" might be indicative of a larger misconception.

Comment: As for targets, I suggest that you watch the classic Session 211 video from WWDC 2010 where all of that was so beautifully and definitively explained. — The rest of your question doesn't interest me, you look behind the scenes, naturally you see a lot of weird stuff.

Comment: I used threads because I wanted to know how it relates to threading.

Comment: Well, that's the problem with the question. It's all so broad and open-ended.

Comment: Unfortunately, Apple has taken down the 2010 videos, and it's been awhile since they really explained this. (I know asciiwwdc still has the transcripts, but has anyone squirreled away the videos online?) But the place to start that is still available is the Concurrency Programming Guide. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Queues are not threads. They don't map cleanly to threads. They don't solve the same problems as threads. They do use threads as an implementation detail (but literally everything uses at least one thread as an implementation detail). The best explanation of that is the "Migrating Away From Threads" section of the above programming guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW1

Comment: If your real question is about the private implementation details (rather than how queues are meant to be used in practice), it's open source (at least the Linux version), so you can explore: https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch

Comment: Thanks for sharing the links! I will check these out. I've also removed all references to threading, and asked about queueing theory instead.

Comment: (While the excellent 2010 video is gone, I do recommend the rest of the concurrency videos to explain these issues. https://developer.apple.com/videos/all-videos/?q=concurr

Comment: xref, ref, and sref are about reference counting and memory management ("xref" is an external reference). They have nothing to do with threads. Barriers are explained in DispatchWorkItemFlags. Before digging too deeply into the private implementation details, I recommend studying the public docs and how GCD is used. You seem to be unfamiliar with the public interface to GCD, which I believe is going to make reverse engineering the private details difficult.

Comment: While the videos are gone, you can read the transcripts here: https://asciiwwdc.com/search?q=dispatch  You'll also want to be research the implementation details of ObjC memory management, and particularly how it is bridged to non-ObjC types (such as dispatch queues). I think you're being confused by reference-counting (i.e. xref), and assuming it's related to internal thread-management. The large negative value for xref and ref, for example, is likely indicating that is an object that cannot be deallocated.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [source](https://apple.github.io/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/post/libdispatch-is-open-source/)?

Comment: I do have the video. But posting it online would risk the attention of Apple’s lawyers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why ask this?

This is a fairly broad question about the internals of `grand-central-dispatch`. I had difficulty understanding the `dump`ed output because the original WWDC '10 videos and slides for GCD are no longer public. I also didn't know about the open-source `libdispatch` repo (thanks Rob). That needn't be a problem, but there are no related QAs on SO explaining the topic in detail.

### Why GCD?

According to the WWDC '10 GCD transcripts (Thanks Rob), the main idea behind the API was to simplify the boilerplate associated with using the `#selector` API for multithreading.

### Benefits of `GCD`

Apple released a new `block`-based API instead of going with function pointers, to also enable type-safe code that wouldn't crash if the block had the wrong type signature. Using `typedef`s also made code cleaner when used in function parameters, local variables and `@property` declarations. Queues allow you to capture code and some state as a chunk of data that get managed, enqueued and executed automatically behind the scenes.

The same session mentions how GCD manages low-level threads under the hood. It enqueues blocks to execute on threads when they need to be executed and then releases those threads (`PThread`s to be precise) when they are no longer referenced. GCD manages threads automatically and doesn't expose this API - when a `DispatchWorkItem` is dequeued GCD creates a thread for this block to execute on.

### Drawbacks of `performSelector`

[`performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1414476-performselector?language=objc) has numerous drawbacks that suggest poor design for the modern challenges of concurrency, waiting, synchronisation. leads to pyramids of doom when switching threads in a `func`. Furthermore, the `NSObject.performSelector` family of threading methods are inflexible and limited:

1. No options to optimise for concurrent, initially inactive, or synchronisation on a particular thread. Unlike [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/attributes).
2. Only *selectors* can be dispatched on to new threads (awful).
3. Lots of threads for a given function leads to messy code (pyramids of doom).
4. No support for queueing without a limited (at the time when GCD was announced in iOS 4) `NSOperation` API. `NSOperation`s are a high-level, verbose API that became more powerful after incorporating elements of dispatch (low-level API that became GCD) in iOS 4.
5. Lots of bugs related to unhandled invalid `Selector` errors (type safety).

### `DispatchQueue` internals

I believe the `xref`, `ref` and `sref` are internal registers that manage reference counts for automatic reference counting. GCD calls `dispatch_retain` and `dispatch_release` in most cases when needed, so we don't need to worry about releasing a queue after all its blocks have been executed. However, there were cases when a developer could call `retain` and `release` manually when trying to ensure the queue is retained even when not directly in use. These registers allow `libDispatch` to crash when `release` is called on a queue with a positive reference count, for better error handling.

When calling a block with `DispatchQueue.global().async` or similar, I believe this increments the reference count of that queue (`xref` and `ref`).

The variables in the question are not documented explicitly, but from what I can tell:

- `xref` counts the number of external references to a general `DispatchQueue`.
- `ref` counts the total number of references to a general `DispatchQueue`.
- `sref` counts the number of references to API serial/concurrent/runloop queues, sources and mach channels (these need to be tracked differently as they are represented using different types).

`in-barrier` looks like an internal state flag (`DispatchWorkItemFlag`) to track whether new work items submitted to a concurrent queue should be scheduled or not. Only once the barrier work item finishes, the queue returns to scheduling work items that were submitted after the barrier. `in-flight` means that there is no barrier in force currently.

`state` is also not documented explicitly but I presume points to memory where the block can access variables from the scope where the block was scheduled.